# How to get a specific value from a Cell which has a lot of data

Tags: regex, google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I want to get only the price's encased in brackets in **Price EUR** cell:

Sheet link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xoNPfIfrVv7jF8W3Pa67Iu9oJRz2NOncW7oLQ94mWQ4

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=IFNA(INDEX(TRIM(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SUBSTITUTE(
 SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT($A3, B1&"(.+)"), "]"), "[", ), 1, 2))), 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you bro for this formula it's working well, but there is a problem when I select the cell and drag bottom to copy the formula for all other cells the A1 changing (example: A4 - A5 - A6 ...) and the B1 also changing and it's the problem because it's too hard to copy-paste some formula for all cells and change the A and B value manually, there is any trick to let me drag the formula for other cells and change the value of A only, hope you understand me and you can help me with that. best regards

Comment: sure, see your sheet